# Testing Campaign App on Facebook as ad

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, ads, facebook-ads-api

I have to integrate the Campaign of my app. I read the tutorial  [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ads-for-apps/mobile-app-ads)

My questions:

1. I don't want to place an actual order now; I want to test it first. Is there any kind of Sandbox for showing the ad?
2. How can I test that is it working correctly if I actually place an order for an ad?

Answer (score 0):

the way it works is when you set up the add and before you pay for it you will be given a view of what the add looks like. you can then right click -> open in new tab to see how the link works to make sure it is working the way you want it to. then you can save it to activate it in the future.

Comment: I know that but does it support any sandbox for only Testing purpose?
and How can I see that my ad is see good on Facebook.

Comment: well the thing is there is no sandbox per say,except that preview box.

Comment: ok, thanks for your answer. How can I test my app install ad?